# setfocus the data in textfield after scan barcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode

i'm using jQuery for my task. 
Then i'm using barcode scanner for input data into my input form.
how do i do to show data(setfocus) in the 2nd textfield, if i have two textfields inside this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the second `<input>` then call [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), like this:

```
$("form input:text:eq(1)").focus()
```

Note that it's `1` because it's a 0-based index.

Comment: are we no need to use textfield ID?